# UnsafeMutablePointer in Swift 3

Tags: c, swift, pointers, swift3

How can I create this function in Swift 3, since `UnsafeMutablePointer` is now `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`?

```
func writeUInt32(value:UInt32) {
    guard let data = NSMutableData(length: 4) else { return }
    UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(data.bytes).memory = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(UInt32(value))
    writeData(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using `NSMutableData` in a bad manner. You should use `mutableBytes` rather than `bytes`.

To work with `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`, check the latest reference.

[UnsafeMutableRawPointer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer)

You can find `storeBytes(of:toByteOffset:as:)` method.

[func storeBytes(of: T, toByteOffset: Int, as: T.Type)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer/2430346-storebytes)

> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> func storeBytes<T>(of value: T, toByteOffset offset: Int = default, as: T.Type)
> ```

Seems the second parameter is optional, so you can write something like this:

```
func writeUInt32(value:UInt32) {
    guard let data = NSMutableData(length: 4) else { return }
    data.mutableBytes.storeBytes(of: CFSwapInt32BigToHost(value), as: UInt32.self)
    writeData(data)
}
```

Or if you want to work with new data type `Data`:

```
func writeUInt32(value:UInt32) {
    var tempValue = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(value)
    let data = Data(bytes: &tempValue, count: MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size)
    writeData(data as NSData)
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should be `CFSwapInt32HostToBig(value)`, or just `value.bigEndian` :)

Comment: @MartinR, thanks. In fact, I am always confused with them including `htonl` and `ntohl`...